# Actual references in scriptures which says Lord Shiva consumes cannabis?

Tags: scripture, shiva

Since we know that Lord Shiva exists in many different forms and worshiped through various forms throughout history, I've heard quite a few stories from people where they say, Lord Shiva consumes cannabis. But when I ask reputable people, they say that his energies were at their peak and he being super-alert with a high sense of perception and that is another kind of intoxication and he's not intoxicated from smoking some plant.

But I would like to know the actual references from the Hindu texts which talk about Lord Shiva consuming cannabis.

Comment: There is nothing of that sort. It's just a false story.